# Bindingcontext error when passing selected item

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to create a bottom nav bar with the `NuGet:ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF`

I hope that I am thinking correctly but this is my setup.

This is the code that is linking to my profile page, here I get the error

```
Severity    Code Description    Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1729  'BottomNavPage' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments   DoggaLogg.Android, DoggaLogg.iOS, DoggaLogg.UWP C:\Users\mawil3\source\repos\DoggaLogg\DoggaLogg\DoggaLogg\View\HomePage.xaml.cs    40  Active
Error   CS1729  'BottomNavPage' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments   DoggaLogg.Android, DoggaLogg.iOS, DoggaLogg.UWP C:\Users\mawil3\source\repos\DoggaLogg\DoggaLogg\DoggaLogg\View\HomePage.xaml.cs    40  Active)
```

```cs
async void ProfileList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new BottomNavPage(BindingContext = e.SelectedItem));
    }
}
```

Here is my bottomnavbar xaml page:

```xml
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DoggaLogg.View.BottomNavPage"
         xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:DoggaLogg.View">


<pages:ProfilePage Title="Profile" Icon="icon" />

<pages:GoalPage Title="Goalse" Icon="icon" /></xf:BottomBarPage>
```

And here Bottomnavbar.cs

```cs
namespace DoggaLogg.View{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class BottomNavPage : ContentPage
{
    public BottomNavPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}}
```

From my understanding `e.selecteditem` should pass through the selected item, or am I wrong?

What could cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `BottomNavPage` like this: `new BottomNavPage(BindingContext = e.SelectedItem)`, but there is no constructor that takes one argument.

It seems you are trying to set the `BindingContext` property of your new page directly. Either pass in your selected item as an argument which requires you to change or add a constructor to your `BottomNavPage` object:

```
public BottomNavPage (object yourItem)
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    BindingContext = yourItem;
}
```

Or, declare the first line like this:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new BottomNavPage()
{
    BindingContext = e.SelectedItem
});
```

This instantiates a new `BottomNavPage` with the parameterless constructor but assigns your selected item to the `BindingContext` immediately after creating the new instance.